# Probability of a value in a distribution defined by ratio of two normal variables (Python)

Tags: python, r, statistics

Let Z = X/Y where X and Y are two normal variables. I know the mean and standard deviation of X and Y. How can I find the probability P( z > a ) where [image]

Comment: This is really a question more suitable for stats.stackexchange.com. That said, take a look at P(Z > a) = P(X > a Y). For a given value of Y, that's an ordinary probability calculation for a normal variable. That's a function of Y, let's call the function foo(Y). Now integrate foo(Y) over possible values of Y, i.e. P(Z > a) = integral(p(Y) foo(Y), Y, -inf, inf) where p(Y) is the probability density for Y.

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking is not so simple, the wikipedia page has a lot of information https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_distribution. In short, the ratio of two normal independent distributions **with zero mean** is a Cauchy distribution, from which you can estimate your desired probability.